# How do I make a MotionEvent to zoom?

Tags: android, testing, instrumentation

I have an instrumentation that I want to use to test my application, but I can't seem to get the pinch zoom to simulate properly. Here is my current code. The gist of it is this: push down both finger 1 and finger 2, move them both closer to one another, then release them both.

```
private void performZoomTest(int numUpdates) {
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();    

    float x1 = 0;
    float y1 = 0;

    Display main = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    float x2 = main.getWidth();
    float y2 = main.getHeight();

    float xstep = x2 / (2 * numUpdates);
    float ystep = y2 / (2 * numUpdates);

    int id1 = 0 << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
    int id2 = 1 << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;

    MotionEvent event = 
        MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN + id1,
                   x1, y1, 0);
    sendPointerSync(event);
    event = 
        MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN + id2,
                   x2, y2, 0);
    sendPointerSync(event);

    waitForIdleSync();

    for (int i = 0; i < numUpdates; i++) {
        eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        Log.i("",Integer.toString(i));
        x1 += xstep;
        y1 += ystep;

        x2 -= xstep;
        y2 -= ystep;

        event = 
            MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                       MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE + id1,
                       x1, y1, 0);
        Log.i("id1", Integer.toString(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE + id1));
        sendPointerSync(event);
        event = 
            MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                       MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE + id2, 
                       x2, y2, 0);
        Log.i("id1", Integer.toString(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE + id2));
        sendPointerSync(event);

        waitForIdleSync();
    } 

    eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    event = 
        MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                   MotionEvent.ACTION_UP + id1, 
                   x1, y1, 0);
    sendPointerSync(event);
    event = 
        MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                   MotionEvent.ACTION_UP + id2, 
                   x2, y2, 0);
    sendPointerSync(event);

    waitForIdleSync();
}
```

The result seems to be that the application treats the two events as being distinct, and doesn't register them as a single event. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps

I think multitouch unit testing is not possible with the standard Android framework.

Comment: How is that possible? There are so many applications that depend on it, how can there be no support for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of exactly what you are doing wrong, but I think that there are some articles out there that may be of assistance to you.

[This blog post from Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) is about dealing with multi-touch, and even shows how you might make a two finger Scale (that is, zoom) gesture that is distinguishable from a one finger slide/scroll/drag gesture.

Here is a [link to the code](http://code.google.com/p/android-touchexample/) from the example.

Comment: I'm not trying to react to a zoom event, I'm trying to cause one to be sent. I want to create a `MotionEvent` identical to the event that would be triggered by a user actually zooming with two fingers.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to create a 'zoom' gesture that is using two fingers.  I believe that is exactly what the link I provided is doing.

Comment: @Alex Did you find the solution? Even I am looking for a way to generate pinch/zoom event in one of my applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the android API **MotionEvent(ACTION_POINTER_DOWN,ACTION_MOVE,
ACTION_POINTER_UP)** would solve the multi-touch problem.
However.I don't know how to get the parameter“numUpdates”.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible, as [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599282/472262) demonstrates. Solves the problem for my setup.