# How to generate zoom/pinch gesture for testing for Android

Tags: android, testing, zooming, gesture

I'm trying to generate zoom/pinch gesture for testing, I have tried to use the Android API MotionEvent.obtain(), but found it is hard to implement the zoom/pinch events.

I referenced the API from [MotionEvent.obtain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain(long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties[],%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords[],%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). Can you tell me the correct method?

Here is my implementation:

```
//for zoom, we need four points coordinations: start0, start1, end0, end1

Instrumentation inst;

// action down event
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1, prop_start0, pointerCoords_start0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
inst.sendPointerSync(event);

// action pointer 2 down event
event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN, 2, properties_start0_1, pointerCoords_start0_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
inst.sendPointerSync(event);

// action move events
duration = 1000; //1000 ms
event_interval = 10;//time interval between consecutive events 10ms 
moveEventNum = duration / event_interval; 
stepx0 = (end0.x - start0.x)/moveEventNum;
stepy0 = (end0.y - start0.y)/moveEventNum;
stepx1 = (end1.x - start1.x)/moveEventNum;
stepy1 = (end1.y - start1.y)/moveEventNum;

move_event0= start0;
move_event1 = start1;
for ( int i = 0; i < moveEventNum; i++) {
       //  [generate middle points here ]
       mov_event0.x += stepx0;
       mov_event0.y += stepy0;
       mov_event1.x += stepx1;
       mov_event1.y += stepy1;

      eventTime += event_interval;

      event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 2, properties_move_event, pointerCoords_move_event0_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 

     inst.sendPointerSync(event);
}

event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP, 2, properties_end0_1, pointerCoords_end0_1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
inst.sendPointerSync(event);

event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1, end1, pointerCoords_end1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
inst.sendPointerSync(event);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend obtaining a device to debug on.  It will be worth it.

Comment: yes, i'm debugging in a device, and trying to generate the zoom gesture for test automation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

well, i have found the issue.

***ISSUE:***

When using the obtain() API, we have to set the pressure and size of the points in each event.

For

```
obtain(long, long, int, int, android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties[], 
android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords[], int, int, float, float, int, int, int, int)
```

the PointerCoords[], we have to set the pressure and size to 1, the default values are 0.

For

```
public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action,
         float x, float y, int metaState)

     Create a new MotionEvent, filling in a subset of the basic motion values. 
    Those not specified here are: device id (always 0), pressure and size (always 1), 
x and y precision (always 1), and edgeFlags (always 0).

since the default pressure and size are 1, so we don't need to set them.
```

***My tips for creating gestures:***

**1. following the real gesture sequence, since we want to simulate the real gestures**

- override the onTouchEvent() to check the real events received by
  application. These events can also be used for comparison of real
  user touch events and generated touch events Take browser for
  example:

  a) @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      Log.i("WebView", event.toString() + event.getAction());     boolean rt
     = super.onTouchEvent(event);     return rt; }
- manually touch screen to get the real gesture sequence from onTouchEvent() in a). We can follow the event sequence when generating events.
  -- If we don’t follow the gesture event sequence, the instrumented events may be rejected.
- Here is a valid event sequence of zoom gesture, (the downTime is the same for all the events)

  i. ACTION_DOWN of one start point

  ii. ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN of two start points

  iii.ACTION_MOVE of two middle points

  iv. ACTION_POINTER_2_UP of two end points

  v.  ACTION_UP of one end point

**2. use the API MotionEvent.obtain correctly**

- There are two most used obtain() API.

***public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action,
         float x, float y, int metaState)***

AND

***public static MotionEvent  obtain(long, long, int, int, android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties[], 
android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords[], int, int, float, float, int, int, int, int)***

The first one is usually used for single point gestures, like fling, scroll, click etc. The parameters (pressure, size, xPresion, yPresion) for this function are all set to 1.

And the second one is a more general one, and can be used for multi-touch events generation. While for the second one, we have to set the pressure, size in pointerCoords of each touch point to 1.

***Here is the example to generate the zoom gesture:***

```
public static void generateZoomGesture(Instrumentation inst,
        long startTime, boolean ifMove, GestureInfo.Point startPoint1,
        GestureInfo.Point startPoint2, GestureInfo.Point endPoint1,
        GestureInfo.Point endPoint2, int duration) {

    if (inst == null || startPoint1 == null
            || (ifMove && endPoint1 == null)) {
        return;
    }

    long eventTime = startTime;
    long downTime = startTime;
    MotionEvent event;
    float eventX1, eventY1, eventX2, eventY2;

    eventX1 = startPoint1.x;
    eventY1 = startPoint1.y;
    eventX2 = startPoint2.x;
    eventY2 = startPoint2.y;

    // specify the property for the two touch points
    PointerProperties[] properties = new PointerProperties[2];
    PointerProperties pp1 = new PointerProperties();
    pp1.id = 0;
    pp1.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER;
    PointerProperties pp2 = new PointerProperties();
    pp2.id = 1;
    pp2.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER;

    properties[0] = pp1;
    properties[1] = pp2;

    //specify the coordinations of the two touch points
    //NOTE: you MUST set the pressure and size value, or it doesn't work
    PointerCoords[] pointerCoords = new PointerCoords[2];
    PointerCoords pc1 = new PointerCoords();
    pc1.x = eventX1;
    pc1.y = eventY1;
    pc1.pressure = 1;
    pc1.size = 1;
    PointerCoords pc2 = new PointerCoords();
    pc2.x = eventX2;
    pc2.y = eventY2;
    pc2.pressure = 1;
    pc2.size = 1;
    pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
    pointerCoords[1] = pc2;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // events sequence of zoom gesture
    // 1. send ACTION_DOWN event of one start point
    // 2. send ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN of two start points
    // 3. send ACTION_MOVE of two middle points
    // 4. repeat step 3 with updated middle points (x,y),
    //      until reach the end points
    // 5. send ACTION_POINTER_2_UP of two end points
    // 6. send ACTION_UP of one end point
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // step 1
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1, properties, 
                pointerCoords, 0,  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

    inst.sendPointerSync(event);

    //step 2
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN, 2, 
                properties, pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    inst.sendPointerSync(event);

    //step 3, 4
    if (ifMove) {
        int moveEventNumber = 1;
        moveEventNumber = duration / EVENT_MIN_INTERVAL;

        float stepX1, stepY1, stepX2, stepY2;

        stepX1 = (endPoint1.x - startPoint1.x) / moveEventNumber;
        stepY1 = (endPoint1.y - startPoint1.y) / moveEventNumber;
        stepX2 = (endPoint2.x - startPoint2.x) / moveEventNumber;
        stepY2 = (endPoint2.y - startPoint2.y) / moveEventNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i < moveEventNumber; i++) {
            // update the move events
            eventTime += EVENT_MIN_INTERVAL;
            eventX1 += stepX1;
            eventY1 += stepY1;
            eventX2 += stepX2;
            eventY2 += stepY2;

            pc1.x = eventX1;
            pc1.y = eventY1;
            pc2.x = eventX2;
            pc2.y = eventY2;

            pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
            pointerCoords[1] = pc2;

            event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 2, properties, 
                        pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            inst.sendPointerSync(event);
        }
    }

    //step 5
    pc1.x = endPoint1.x;
    pc1.y = endPoint1.y;
    pc2.x = endPoint2.x;
    pc2.y = endPoint2.y;
    pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
    pointerCoords[1] = pc2;

    eventTime += EVENT_MIN_INTERVAL;
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP, 2, properties, 
                pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);

    // step 6
    eventTime += EVENT_MIN_INTERVAL;
    event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1, properties, 
                pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    inst.sendPointerSync(event);
}
```

Comment: MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN seems to be deprecated but if we use MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP it does not work. Do you know the reason?

Comment: For espresso, implement au `ViewAction`. Then replace `Instrumentation` with `UiController` and replace `inst.sendPointerSync(event);` with `uiController.injectMotionEvent(event);`. Finally place `generateZoomGesture` method call in the `perform` method.

Comment: I'm very interested in this example but can't figure out how to implement it for an Espresso UI test. Can you guys post an example of zooming gesture for Espresso?

Comment: What is the GestureInfo class?

Comment: @Täg please share more information about how to achieve it in espresso, if possible with code, Better if you leave a comment in this post

Comment: One year later, I have finally dealt in another way.
First, initialize a UIObject2 (using UIAutomator with minSDK > 18). This is not really efficient and unpredictable… There is some code… (good luck)

{
    String packageName = instrumentation.getTargetContext().getPackageName();
    BySelector viewSelector = By.res(packageName, "viewId");
    UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation);
    uiObject2 = uiDevice.findObject(uiObject2Selector);
 }       

Finally, to use it: 
{
    uiObject2.pinchOpen(0.75f);
}

And because this is unpredictable, I remove this test

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in a comment by Täg, this can be used with Espresso. Here is my code for doing this in Espresso, based on the very good answer from longchuan and the update form peetasan.

In the Espresso test:

```
// Pinch out (to zoom in):
onView(withId(R.id.MyViewId)).perform(pinchOut());
```

The helper methods, which includes a nice way to get the correct coordinates from the view, and also includes correct error handling for `uiController.injectMotionEvent(event)`:

```
public static ViewAction pinchOut() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return ViewMatchers.isEnabled();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Pinch out";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            Point middlePosition = getCenterPoint(view);

            final int startDelta = 0; // How far from the center point each finger should start
            final int endDelta = 500; // How far from the center point each finger should end (note: Be sure to have this large enough so that the gesture is recognized!)

            Point startPoint1 = new Point(middlePosition.x - startDelta, middlePosition.y);
            Point startPoint2 = new Point(middlePosition.x + startDelta, middlePosition.y);
            Point endPoint1 = new Point(middlePosition.x - endDelta, middlePosition.y);
            Point endPoint2 = new Point(middlePosition.x + endDelta, middlePosition.y);

            performPinch(uiController, startPoint1, startPoint2, endPoint1, endPoint2);
        }
    };
}

public static ViewAction pinchIn() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return ViewMatchers.isEnabled();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Pinch in";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            Point middlePosition = getCenterPoint(view);

            final int startDelta = 500; // How far from the center point each finger should start (note: Be sure to have this large enough so that the gesture is recognized!)
            final int endDelta = 0; // How far from the center point each finger should end

            Point startPoint1 = new Point(middlePosition.x - startDelta, middlePosition.y);
            Point startPoint2 = new Point(middlePosition.x + startDelta, middlePosition.y);
            Point endPoint1 = new Point(middlePosition.x - endDelta, middlePosition.y);
            Point endPoint2 = new Point(middlePosition.x + endDelta, middlePosition.y);

            performPinch(uiController, startPoint1, startPoint2, endPoint1, endPoint2);
        }
    };
}

@NonNull
private static Point getCenterPoint(View view) {
    int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);
    float viewHeight = view.getHeight() * view.getScaleY();
    float viewWidth = view.getWidth() * view.getScaleX();
    return new Point(
            (int) (locationOnScreen[0] + viewWidth / 2),
            (int) (locationOnScreen[1] + viewHeight / 2));
}

private static void performPinch(UiController uiController, Point startPoint1, Point startPoint2, Point endPoint1, Point endPoint2) {
    final int duration = 500;
    final long eventMinInterval = 10;
    final long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long eventTime = startTime;
    MotionEvent event;
    float eventX1, eventY1, eventX2, eventY2;

    eventX1 = startPoint1.x;
    eventY1 = startPoint1.y;
    eventX2 = startPoint2.x;
    eventY2 = startPoint2.y;

    // Specify the property for the two touch points
    MotionEvent.PointerProperties[] properties = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties[2];
    MotionEvent.PointerProperties pp1 = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
    pp1.id = 0;
    pp1.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER;
    MotionEvent.PointerProperties pp2 = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
    pp2.id = 1;
    pp2.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER;

    properties[0] = pp1;
    properties[1] = pp2;

    // Specify the coordinations of the two touch points
    // NOTE: you MUST set the pressure and size value, or it doesn't work
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] pointerCoords = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords[2];
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords pc1 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
    pc1.x = eventX1;
    pc1.y = eventY1;
    pc1.pressure = 1;
    pc1.size = 1;
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords pc2 = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
    pc2.x = eventX2;
    pc2.y = eventY2;
    pc2.pressure = 1;
    pc2.size = 1;
    pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
    pointerCoords[1] = pc2;

    /*
     * Events sequence of zoom gesture:
     *
     * 1. Send ACTION_DOWN event of one start point
     * 2. Send ACTION_POINTER_DOWN of two start points
     * 3. Send ACTION_MOVE of two middle points
     * 4. Repeat step 3 with updated middle points (x,y), until reach the end points
     * 5. Send ACTION_POINTER_UP of two end points
     * 6. Send ACTION_UP of one end point
     */

    try {
        // Step 1
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(startTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 1, properties,
                pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        injectMotionEventToUiController(uiController, event);

        // Step 2
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(startTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN + (pp2.id << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT), 2,
                properties, pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        injectMotionEventToUiController(uiController, event);

        // Step 3, 4
        long moveEventNumber = duration / eventMinInterval;

        float stepX1, stepY1, stepX2, stepY2;

        stepX1 = (endPoint1.x - startPoint1.x) / moveEventNumber;
        stepY1 = (endPoint1.y - startPoint1.y) / moveEventNumber;
        stepX2 = (endPoint2.x - startPoint2.x) / moveEventNumber;
        stepY2 = (endPoint2.y - startPoint2.y) / moveEventNumber;

        for (int i = 0; i < moveEventNumber; i++) {
            // Update the move events
            eventTime += eventMinInterval;
            eventX1 += stepX1;
            eventY1 += stepY1;
            eventX2 += stepX2;
            eventY2 += stepY2;

            pc1.x = eventX1;
            pc1.y = eventY1;
            pc2.x = eventX2;
            pc2.y = eventY2;

            pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
            pointerCoords[1] = pc2;

            event = MotionEvent.obtain(startTime, eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 2, properties,
                    pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            injectMotionEventToUiController(uiController, event);
        }

        // Step 5
        pc1.x = endPoint1.x;
        pc1.y = endPoint1.y;
        pc2.x = endPoint2.x;
        pc2.y = endPoint2.y;
        pointerCoords[0] = pc1;
        pointerCoords[1] = pc2;

        eventTime += eventMinInterval;
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(startTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP + (pp2.id << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT), 2, properties,
                pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        injectMotionEventToUiController(uiController, event);

        // Step 6
        eventTime += eventMinInterval;
        event = MotionEvent.obtain(startTime, eventTime,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 1, properties,
                pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        injectMotionEventToUiController(uiController, event);
    } catch (InjectEventSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not perform pinch", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Safely call uiController.injectMotionEvent(event): Detect any error and "convert" it to an
 * IllegalStateException
 */
private static void injectMotionEventToUiController(UiController uiController, MotionEvent event) throws InjectEventSecurityException {
    boolean injectEventSucceeded = uiController.injectMotionEvent(event);
    if (!injectEventSucceeded) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error performing event " + event);
    }
}
```

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. Awesome work.

One suggestion would be to add `uiController.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(duration)` after Step 6 completes inside `performPinch()`. This prevents the test from continuing on until the gesture has finished.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just one note: If you leave `startDelta` at 0, the view you are trying to "pinch" may disappear. Android seems to act weird when the two "fingers" appear exactly in the same spot. Might be some divide-by-0 math happening.

Comment: Also an additional bug: When `stepX1`, `stepY1`, etc are calculated in `performPinch`, you are dividing  `int` by an `int` to get a `float`. This can produce roundoff / typecasting errors.

I cast `moveEventNumber` as a `float` and that fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

In order to make the above code work with non-deprecated constants I used
`MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN + (pp2.id << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT)` instead of `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN`

So I had to replace this line:

> event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
>                   MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN, 2, 
>                   properties, pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

with

> event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, 
>                       MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN + (pp2.id << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT), 2, 
>                       properties, pointerCoords, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Thanks for posting this update! I made the assumption of using ACTION_POINTER_UP/DOWN but didn't realize that the mask was needed. This saved me a big headache!