# How can I test pinch gesture using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, junit

I want to test the pinch gesture on my main activity using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
I tested a lot of other features in my main activity  but I still don't know how can I test the pinch gesture , How can I do that ?

Comment: finally I found my answer in another stackoverflow question [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11599282/1327384