# Simulate Multitouch Event In Android Programmatically For Testing

Tags: android, testing, multi-touch

I need to simulate multitouch events (zoom, pan, etc) to use in instrumentation tests of the Android app. One way would be to manually generate corresponding sequence of [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)s that imitate real input, and then dispatch them one by one. Before I do that, is there some nice API that does such simulation? I imagine a lot of people faced this issue in the past. I was looking into [Robotium Solo](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html), but it only provides touch/drag for single pointer.

If there's no such API, what would be the best way to approach the problem? I was thinking to write a function that accepts a pair of points (start, end) and duration for each participating pointer, but this would limit gestures to linear pointer motion.

```
public void twoFingerTouchEvent(
             Point from1, Point to1, int duration1, 
             Point from2, Point to2, int duration2) {

  if (from1.equals(to1) && from2.equals(to2)) { 
    // two pointer tap
    // DISPATCH_DOWN
    // DISPATCH_POINTER_DOWN
    // WAIT min(duration1, duration2)
    // DISPATCH_POINTER_UP
    // WAIT abs(duration1 - duration2)
    // DISPATCH_UP
  }
  else if (from1.equals(to1) || from2.equals(to2)) {
    // one of two pointers dragged after tap
    // DISPATCH_DOWN
    // DISPATCH_POINTER_DOWN
    // DISPATCH_MOVE for moving pointer every 3-5 pixels, account for duration
    // DISPATCH_POINTER_UP
    // DISPATCH_UP 
  }
  else {
    // two pointer drag
    // DISPATCH_DOWN
    // DISPATCH_POINTER_DOWN
    // DISPATCH_MOVE for both pointers in alternating order every 3-5 pixels
    // DISPATCH_POINTER_UP
    // DISPATCH_MOVE for pointer with longer duration
    // DISPATCH_UP 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [MotionEvent#obtain](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords%5B%5D,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) - it can be used to create a MotionEvent containing multiple pointers.
You are not limited to linear pointer motion - you can pass array of points and perform one action down, then x times action move and finally action up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you happen to know how to simulate multitouch for API < 9? This method seems to accept pointerCount, but only coordinates of one pointer. So I'm not sure how to use it to obtain needed events:


Introduced in API 5:
public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, float x, float y, float pressure, float size, int metaState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags)

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the documentation for [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html):

For API 9 and below, you'll want to use the MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_X_DOWN/UP to specify which pointer is going up or down.

The event sequence is an ACTION_DOWN for the first contact, followed by ACTION_POINTER_X_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_X_UP as new contacts are added or removed, until you will finally have the last ACTION_UP event to 'lift' the last contact.

```
(actionId, pointerCount)
ACTION_DOWN, 1 // initial contact
ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN, 2
ACTION_MOVE, 2 // generate a two-touch drag/zoom event
ACTION_POINTER_2_UP, 2
ACTION_UP, 1
```

I was basing from this SO post: [How to generate zoom/pinch gesture for testing for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523423/how-to-generate-zoom-pinch-gesture-for-testing-for-android)