# How to scroll a Pager programatically AND smoothly

Tags: user-interface, android-viewpager, android

I'm using this code to scroll programatically my pager

```
public void MoveNext(View view) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}

public void MovePrevious(View view) {

    pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);

}
```

The code work perfect but the transition is too fast. How can I introduce a delay so that the scrolling would be done more smoothly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there are two ways can achieve this goal, I've tried by ViewPager's `fakeDrag()` but which doesn't work perfect, luckly, another way does, by simulate touch motion event and use `ObjectAnimator` to specify the animation duration then make control the scroll speed become true.

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener, Animator.AnimatorListener {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private View btnTriggerNext;
    private View btnTriggerPrev;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...) {
        super...;
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_xml);

        mViewPager = findViewById(...);

        btnTriggerNext = findViewById(R.id.btnTriggerNext);
        btnTriggerNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnTriggerPrev = findViewById(R.id.btnTriggerPrev);
        btnTriggerPrev.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private boolean mIsInAnimation;
    private long mMotionBeginTime;
    private float mLastMotionX;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mIsInAnimation) return;
        ObjectAnimator anim;

        if (v == btnTriggerPrev) {
            if (!hasPrevPage()) return;
            anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "motionX", 0, mViewPager.getWidth());
        }
        else if (v == btnTriggerNext) {
            if (!hasNextPage()) return;
            anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "motionX", 0, -mViewPager.getWidth());
        }
        else return;

        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.addListener(this);
        anim.setDuration(300);
        anim.start();
    }

    public void setMotionX(float motionX) {
        if (!mIsInAnimation) return;
        mLastMotionX = motionX;
        final long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        simulate(MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, mMotionBeginTime, time);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        mIsInAnimation = false;
        final long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        simulate(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, mMotionBeginTime, time);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        mLastMotionX = 0;
        mIsInAnimation = true;
        final long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        simulate(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, time, time);
        mMotionBeginTime = time;
    }

    // method from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11599282/1294681
    private void simulate(int action, long startTime, long endTime) {
        // specify the property for the two touch points
        MotionEvent.PointerProperties[] properties = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties[1];
        MotionEvent.PointerProperties pp = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
        pp.id = 0;
        pp.toolType = MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER;

        properties[0] = pp;

        // specify the coordinations of the two touch points
        // NOTE: you MUST set the pressure and size value, or it doesn't work
        MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] pointerCoords = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords[1];
        MotionEvent.PointerCoords pc = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
        pc.x = mLastMotionX;
        pc.pressure = 1;
        pc.size = 1;
        pointerCoords[0] = pc;

        final MotionEvent ev = MotionEvent.obtain(
                startTime, endTime, action, 1, properties,
                pointerCoords, 0,  0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        mViewPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    private boolean hasPrevPage() {
        return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0;
    }

    private boolean hasNextPage() {
        return mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1 < mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
    }
}
```

cause it was simulating touch event, so please use a proper duration(less than 600ms will be nice) to do scrolling, when scroll in progress, put down finger would stop it and cause some bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
```

to

```
pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
```

This will call the method [setCurrentItem(int item,boolean smoothScroll)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) which will scroll smoothly to the mentioned `item` instead of transitioning immediately