# Trigger ACTION_POINTER_DOWN event programmatically

Tags: android, android-touch-event

want to trigger `on two fingers down` event for a few milliseconds.

I am able to trigger simple touch event by using this code:

```
 objImageView.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
                    int xa = coords[0];
                    int ys = coords[1];
                    objImageView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, xa, ys, 0.5f, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
                    objImageView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, xa, ys, 0.5f, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
                    objImageView.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, xa, ys, 0.5f, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
```

Now if I try to do the same for ACTION_POINTER_DOWN nothing is happening. Here is my code:

```
  int[] coords = new int[2];
        parentLayout.getLocationOnScreen(coords);
        int xa = coords[0];
        int ys = coords[1];
        parentLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, xa, ys, 0.5f, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
        parentLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, xa, ys, 0.5f, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
        parentLayout.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(0, 0, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP, xa, ys, 0.5f, 5, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0));
```

I want to trigger the same event which called when user places the two fingers down and hold fingers there for a few milliseconds.

Comment: Well, I am still unable to perform the action, For now, I am calling the codes of TouchListener forcefully by writing them in the other method.

Comment: Why exactly would you use action pointer? If you want to be able to trigger every few milliseconds, use a thread with a Timer or another timing event. Extract the onTouch code into a void and trigger it from both thread and onTouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate "two fingers" you will need to create a motion event that includes more than **one** pointer, as you do now.

To do that, use the `MotionEvent obtain` variation that supports multiple pointers as is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain(long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties[],%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords[],%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

```
MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, 
                long eventTime, 
                int action, 
                int pointerCount, 
                PointerProperties[] pointerProperties, 
                PointerCoords[] pointerCoords, 
                int metaState, 
                int buttonState, 
                float xPrecision, 
                float yPrecision, 
                int deviceId, 
                int edgeFlags, 
                int source, 
                int flags)
```

First you should dispatch an event for the first finger (exactly like you did) and when you are about to simulate `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`you should use the above `obtain` variation.

Fields are pretty self explanatory, make sure the params are:

1. pointerCount = 2
2. pointerProperties = [firstFingerPointerProperties, secondFingerPointerProperties]
3. pointerCoords = [firstFingerPointerCoords, secondFingerPointerCoords]

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) said that: "A gesture starts with a motion event with ACTION_DOWN that provides the location of the first pointer down. As each additional pointer that goes down or up, the framework will generate a motion event with ACTION_POINTER_DOWN or ACTION_POINTER_UP accordingly." so You need trigger simple touch event at first. And take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523423/how-to-generate-zoom-pinch-gesture-for-testing-for-android) question.

Comment: Thanks @Andriy I will check those

Comment: @SyedaZunairah what code have you tried? You should try a sequence like this: `ACTION_DOWN` -> `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` -> optionally small delay -> `ACTION_POINTER_UP` -> `ACTION_UP`

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a sequence like this: `ACTION_DOWN` -> `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` -> optionally small delay -> `ACTION_POINTER_UP` -> `ACTION_UP`.

You should also set pointer index (and other metadata) correctly for second pointer, because otherwise the gesture detection code may be unable to tell that `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` for secondary press is describing a secondary finger, not primary.

Use [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain(long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties[],%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords[],%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to fill in all necessary information for ACTION_POINTER_DOWN describing second press. *Make sure to pass correct `pointerProperties`*!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but since, none of the answers were complete, adding a bit more info here for future folks. Like the author I wanted simulate two touches, and even though my sequence wa:

```
ACTION_DOWN(0), PointerCount = 1
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(5), PointerCount = 2
ACTION_POINTER_UP(6), PointerCount = 2
ACTION_UP(1), PointerCount = 1
```

It was simply not working, I only then understood, that you need to shift action by pointer count.

```
if ((action == ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || action == ACTION_POINTER_UP) && pointerCount > 1)
   action |= 256 << (pointerCount - 2);
```

In other words, the action values become

```
ACTION_DOWN(0), PointerCount = 1
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN(261), PointerCount = 2
ACTION_POINTER_UP(262), PointerCount = 2
ACTION_UP(1), PointerCount = 1
```

Only then it started working for me